# Tell SSH to to use special IdentityFile for special user

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I need to tell SSH to use special IdentityFile for special user.

For example host specs `wizard@host1.com` `wizard@any-other-host.org` should use key `~/.ssh/id_wizard`

I'd like to write

```
User wizard
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_wizard
```

but there is no such option in `man ssh_config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [**Match** directive](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Match). **Match** is a more generalized form of the **Host** directive:

> **Match**
>   Restricts the following declarations (up to the next Host or Match
>   keyword) to be used only when the conditions following the Match
>   keyword are satisfied. Match conditions are specified using one or
>   more criteria or the single token all which always matches. The
>   available criteria keywords are: canonical, exec, host, originalhost,
>   **user**, and localuser. The all criteria must appear alone or immediately
>   after canonical. Other criteria may be combined arbitrarily. All
>   criteria but all and canonical require an argument. Criteria may be
>   negated by prepending an exclamation mark (‘!’).
>   ...
>   The other keywords' criteria must be single entries or comma-separated
>   lists and may use the wildcard and negation operators described in the
>   PATTERNS section. ... **The user keyword
>   matches against the target username on the remote host.**

So:

```
Match user wizard
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_wizard
```